# linux source a symbolic link

Tags: linux, zsh

I have a bash script which i want to call from any directory, but i don't want to add the directory it is in to PATH as it is filled with lots of other scripts which will just clutter.

The script in question manipulates environment variables, so i have to source it.
I tried creating an alias

```
alias  aliastoscript="/path/to/script" 
source aliastoscript #This does not work says no such file
```

I also can't copy the script itself to a different location as it depends on the directory structure and other scripts in the directory.

So i tried a symlink to a location already in path:

```
ln -s /path/to/script /directory/already/in/path/myscript
```

But this does not work either:

```
source myscript #says no such file exists
```

Can anyone suggest how i achieve this? And why does the symlink approach not work?

If it makes any difference, i am using a zsh shell on ubuntu 14.04

**EDIT:**

The answer given below works, but i also wanted to know why the symlink approach was not working.
Here is the sequence of commands

```
ln -s /path/to/script /directory/already/in/path/myscript
#Now there is a symlink called myscript in a directory which is in PATH

source myscript arg1 #This throws an error saying no such file myscript,    
#but it is not supposed to happen because myscript resides in a directory which is in PATH
```

**EDIT 2:**
I just figured what i was doing wrong, the symlink i created, i had used relative paths, totally stupid of me, using absolute paths it worked like a charm.

Comment: why you dont just source "/path/to/script" ?

Comment: Aliases are not variables; they can only be used in *command* position, not as arguments to commands.

Comment: @erwan because the script was deep into nested 6 directories which i didn't want to type every time

Comment: @chepner it is still a valid problem, that he's created a soft link and couldn't source it. Typo perhaps?

Comment: Actually, since he is using zsh, not bash (tag corrected), he *could* use `alias -g aliastoscript="/path/to/script"`.

Comment: [Post Edit #1] Vikash: I see only two ways this could fail, 1) `/path/to/script` is not absolute. 2) `/directory/already/in/path/` is not really in path.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the edit, i was a bit confused because the script i am sourcing was a bash script, i still don't get why the symlink failed though

Comment: If you are using `zsh`, you cannot reliable source a `bash` script; they are two completely different shells.

Comment: @chepner It was not that at all, anyway the script had the shebang line telling it to use bash, i had used relative paths to create a symlink, using absolute paths fixed the issue.

Comment: And why not just `alias myscript="source /patch/to/script"`? That way you just run `myscript` from the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing: 
`alias  aliastoscript="/path/to/script"`

with: 
`export  aliastoscript="/path/to/script"`

Comment: This works fine i just forgot to use the $ before the variable.

Comment: You don't need to export the variable.

Comment: True, `export` is not really needed.

Comment: I just added the export line to my .zshenv and now everytime i can just call it like my script was in path, except for the $ of course.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$` missing in front of the variable name.

```
source $aliastoscript
```

You do not need soft link for the source. The complete file name should work. Better is

```
source /path/to/script
```

Comment: Oh you are right about the alias, thanks, but the reason for the symlink was, i just didn't want to type the path name every time it was very long.

Comment: I thought that'd be your requirement, while Jay's answer works too, I think mine is closer to your requirement. And he's right, you need not create soft-links either way.

Comment: Cool, but can you tell why the soft link didn't work, i thought it was supposed to.

Comment: can you try `source ./myscript`. `source` needs the file path.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to, this is curious. Can you give the commands and their output?